# Different Kaplan-Meier Results with Interval2

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I've noticed a slight difference between `survfit` when I use a survival object of type "interval2".  I first noticed that the number at risk on the interval2 fit was not an integer. I've stepped through `survfit.formula` and `surviftKM` but I'm still not clear as to exactly what's happening and why. Would anyone explain the difference to me?  When debugging it appears `survfitKM` is using some .05 weights (`casewt` variable), but I'm not setting that explicitly.

MRE:

```
library('survival')
surv_obj <- with(lung, Surv(time = time, event = status == 1))

left <- lung$time
right <- ifelse(lung$status == 1, lung$time, NA) 
surv_obj_int <- Surv(time = left, time2 = right, type = 'interval2')

surv_fit <- survfit(surv_obj~1, type = 'kaplan-meier')
surv_fit_int <- survfit(surv_obj_int~1, type = 'kaplan-meier')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The repo owner was kind enough to explain.

> When there is interval censored data the code uses the Turnbull estimate (survfitTurnbull). In this case the number at risk is not well defined and the code uses a "working" value. In your particular example there are no interval censored observations, and it if twas smarter the code would notice that and use survfitKM: more accurate and a lot faster. But users don't tend to use interval2 style unless they need it.

Although, I'm treating lung as interval censored, there are no actual intervals. If there is a right value, it always equals the left.